# C#: Save multiple images to a single file

Tags: c#, image, stream

I am working on a class that maintains a dictionary of images. 
This dictionary should be saved to and loaded from a file.

I implemented the below solution, but the problem is that according to MSDN 
documentation for Image.FromStream();  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=VS.80).aspx

"The stream is reset to zero if this method is called successively with the same stream."

Any ideas how to fix this? The speed of loading the dictionary is critical.

```
class ImageDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<string, Image> dict = new Dictionary<string, Image>();

    public void AddImage(string resourceName, string filename)
    {
       //...
    }

    public Image GetImage(string resourceName) 
    {
       //...
    }


    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        writer.Write((Int32) dict.Count);
        foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
        {
            writer.Write(key);

            Image img;
            dict.TryGetValue(key, out img);
            img.Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        writer.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }

    public void Load(string filename)
    {
        var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        Int32 count = reader.ReadInt32();
        dict.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string key = reader.ReadString();
            Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            dict.Add(key, img);

        }

        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();

    }



}
```

Comment: Note another line in the linked documentation that says: *You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Image.FromStream` method expects a valid image stream. You are concatenating multiple images into a single file and if you want to reconstruct them you will also need to save their size in addition to their number. An easier solution would be to simply binary serialize the image dictionary:

```
public void Save(string filename)
{
    var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = File.Create(filename))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, dict);
    }
}

public void Load(string filename)
{
    var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        dict = (Dictionary<string, Image>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to serialize/deserialize your dictionary `dict` to/from file.

Answer (score 0):

An off-the-wall idea that *might* work (I have definitely not tested this):

- Create a `Substream` class that derives from `Stream` and also wraps an underlying `Stream`.  Its constructor would take a `Stream` and an `offset` into that stream that the `Substream` treats as zero.  `Substream` is basically a constrained view or window into another stream (in this case, your file stream).
- Initially, create a `Substream` over your `FileStream` with an `offset` of zero.
- When you call `Image.FromStream`, the position of your `Substream` will advance to some new position (call this `p`).
- Create a new `Substream` over your `FileStream` with an `offset` of `p`.
- Loop until finished.

The idea is that even if `Image.FromStream` resets the underlying stream, it will reset the `Substream` to some offset into the `FileStream`, which is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

why not create custom header for that file which includes (number of images,starting address of the actual images and make between each image a line separator)